# "Bride price" as an alternative word to "dowry" in Arabic societies

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

In Arabic countries, specially among Muslims, the sum of money given as a gift in a marriage is given by the man to the woman and not by the woman to the man.

Using the word "dowry" in Arabic countries when speaking to a native English speaker may be confusing.

Is the word "bride price" common? Do native speakers understand it?

Bride price as defined by Collins Dictionary is

> (in some societies) money, property, or services given by a bridegroom to the kinsmen of his bride in order to establish his rights over the woman

Comment: I suppose the problem with the wording 'bride price' is that it gives the impression of buying a woman, which some people (or perhaps most people) would equate with slavery. The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/57319?rskey=Vy6gs8&result=1#eid) lists the meaning of 'dowry' as _A present or gift given by a man to or for his bride._ which is not a matter of 'purchase' but of gift.

Comment: @NigelJ (a) it is a payment and has been since the practice started and women were considered chattel; (b) dowry means what is given by the bride or her family to the groom, but OP is asking about what is given by the groom or his family to the bride. That means *dowry* is not only incorrect but diametrically opposite to what’s needed. OP, yes, native speakers will understand *bride price*; it’s the common term for that practice, and educated speakers will have been taught it, and it’s such a simple person’s that anyone who hasn’t will be able to work it out directly.

Comment: I thought I knew what "bride price" meant until I read this question (essentially, money/etc. given to *the bride's **kinsmen***). But I see OP himself defines it as assets given *to the **woman***, which I assume means ***the bride herself.*** So where once there was clarity, now there's just confusion for me. Translated into ELU terminology, that makes the whole issue POB.

Comment: I've heard/seen the term many times, and I *think* I understand what it means.

Comment: @Dan Bron Dower can mean  "The portion of a deceased husband's estate which the law allows to his widow for her life. tenant in dower, the widow who thus holds land. †lady of dower, dowager lady".  Many entailed estates have a dower house, to which the widow of the owner of the estate moves after the owner dies.  The new owner (who is not necessarily the widow's son) moves into the main house.  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/57190?rskey=ohLwNF&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid) and lots of English novels.

Comment: @ab2 That is *dower*, not *dower**y***. The difference is as large as between (and for the same reasons) *Mari**o*** and *Mari**a***. And since *dowery* is relatively well-known but *dower* rare to the point of obscurity, when you say *dower*, people will likely hear *dowery*, and understand you to have said the precise opposite of what you meant.

Comment: I can't speak for everyone, but as a native English speaker I know what a bride price is, as distinct from a dowry.

Comment: @Dan Bron Yes, I know the difference, but most people do not.  Dower will be often misunderstood and dowery may be misused.  Both will need clarification most of the time.  As for bride price, that too will need clarification outside of its native culture.

Comment: @ab2 I do not think *dowery* will be misused, and I think *dower* will never be used. It it wrong to suggest *dower* for that reason, and wrong to suggest *dowery* because it has the exact opposite meaning and people will understand the opposite of what you want them to understand. I think *bride price* is obvious on its face, and almost anyone would understand it even if they heard it for the first time (it’s the *price* for a *bride*); I already elaborated on this in my first comment. Net net: *dowery*, no, *dower*, extra no, *bride price*, workable.

Comment: The reason why I think the word dowry might be possible to refer to the opposite meaning is here:
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/dowry?q=dowry

OALD in definition two :

"money and/or property that, in some societies, a husband must pay to his wife’s family when they get married"

Comment: To clarify more :bride price in Arabic country is a sum of money or rarely a property that must be given to the woman. We call it "mahr" and it is not an optional thing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers .Well,bride price is a gift to the woman herself but in most cases this is given to her father or kinsmen and they must give to her .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, "dowry" and "bride price" are two different things:

> While bride price or bride service is a payment by the groom or his family to the bride's parents, dowry is the wealth transferred from the bride's family to the groom or his family, ostensibly for the bride. Similarly, dower is the property settled on the bride herself, by the groom at the time of marriage, and which remains under her ownership and control.
> <sub>[Wikipedia: Dowry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dowry)</sub>

---

Your main question, whether "bride price" will be understood or not, is tricky to answer.

Personally, I know what a dowry is, but I'm not sure if I've ever heard of a bride price before. "Bride price" is simply not as common an expression: looking at [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), there are 551 hits for "dowry" and only 44 for "bride price".

Looking at various articles written about bride price, many (but not all) of them define what "bride price" is. Here are some examples of articles that do that:

- [Bride Price Practices in Africa](https://afrolegends.com/2018/01/05/bride-price-practices-in-africa/)
- [CCTV: Bride Prices in China Are Sky-High](https://www.whatsonweibo.com/cctv-research-bride-prices-in-china-are-sky-high/)
- [The surprising benefits of bride price for women](https://www.cifar.ca/assets/the-surprising-benefits-of-bride-price-for-women/)
- [Bride Price and Female Education](https://scholar.harvard.edu/nunn/publications/bride-price-and-returns-education-women)

If you're not sure if people will understand what you mean by "bride price", you should give a short definition just to be sure.

Comment: Good distinction between dowry and dower.  However, all or part of the dower may terminate at the end of the bride's life and she may have no control over parts of the dower; for example, she cannot sell the dower house, and probably cannot make structural changes to it beyond repairs.